# Make report viewer body invisible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a report viewer whose body I want to make invisible except for head where you can choose the desired format. Here's my `ASP.NET` code:

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server" ID="report" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Calibri" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="383px" Height="30px">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="ReportFatture.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource2" Name="DataSet2" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Is there any property I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code in `Page Load` to hide report body

```
report.ShowReportBody = false;
```

Again you can make it visible like below

```
report.ShowReportBody = true;
```

[Here's MSDN link for ReportViewer.ShowReportBody Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.showreportbody.aspx)

Comment: Doing so, I can't show the toolbar. I mean everything's gone.

Comment: @NerdNord Can you add screen shot in your question.

Comment: Hey mate, the page is almost blank. It shows just a "Previous page" button at the bottom of the page. If I use ShowReportBody property it definitely won't show anything on my page. http://i.stack.imgur.com/9wqsP.jpg